# "A fallacy in its own right"

Tags: nouns, word-usage

Would it be correct to say or write that an "organisation is a fallacy in its own right" — by failing utterly in doing what it's supposed to do?

Comment: You also mean "in **its** own right"...

Comment: I think it's General Reference that a ***fallacy*** doesn't mean "something which fails to achieve its aim". That's a ***failure***, and I'm closevoting because it seems to me OP hasn't checked dictionary definitions before asking here.

Answer (score 2):

The usual meaning of the term *fallacy* is a type or class of error in reasoning, or an instance of that class. OED sense 3.a.:

> a flaw, material or formal, which vitiates a syllogism; any of the species or types to which such flaws are reducible.

An organization could conceivably be (and indeed many are) characterized by fallacy in OED sense 2.b., “Deceptiveness, aptness to mislead, unreliability,” of which the most recent example given refers to “the fallacy of our senses” (1847, where 3.b. has examples to 1967). But for simply “failing utterly in doing what it's supposed to do” an organization is (as Josh61 comments) rightly termed a *failure,* not a *fallacy.*

Answer (score 2):

A fallacy is an argument which is logically invalid, either because it is internally inconsistent or because it relies on postulates which are false or unsupported.

A word on its own cannot be said to be a fallacy, unless that word stands for some kind of argument.  As [user84593](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185190/being-a-fallacy-in-its-own-right#answer-185191) says, "banks" cannot be a fallacy, because simply saying "banks" is not an argument-- it doesn't assert the truth or falsehood of anything.  You *could* perhaps say "objectivism is a fallacy", because "objectivism" does represent a body of arguments which might be fallacious.

It is better to be more precise here, because imprecise language and careful reasoning are not a good mix.  The original question is apparently focusing on a narrow meaning of the word "organisation" so it would be better to tease that out, and in doing so the question might answer itself.  I have a feeling the OP is looking to say something like "'organisation' is an oxymoron".

Answer (score 0):

A statement can be a fallacy, but not an organization. "Only some people are mortal" is a fallacy. "Banks are a fallacy" is an incorrect usage of fallacy, whatever you may think of banks.

Comment: There are many uses of extended senses on the internet. eg _Benefits of 'green' energy are a fallacy._ (The supposition that green energy has net benefits is a fallacy.) / _Signs of spring are a fallacy._ (The interpretation of various natural phenomena as proving that we are justified in saying that spring has arrived is fallacious.) _'1967 borders' are a fallacy_ (If you think that the 1967 Border Agreements are working / being adhered to / sustainable, you're deluded.) // [The imagined benefits of] [_d_]_iets are a fallacy._

Comment: ... You can see that these are often obvious shortened forms. You can also see why they are often preferred. Some of the dictionary definitions I've checked could be interpreted as licensing these extended, looser senses ('fallacy = something somehow connected with fallacious reasoning) allowing non-concept abstract, and even concrete referents, as subjects.

Answer (score -1):

A word that comes to mind for this situation is the word **paradox**:
A self-contradictory statement, which can only be true if it is false, and vice versa.